# javascript set cookie with language value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I need to set a cookie that saves the language value selected from a drop-down menu in page 1 and carry the cookie until page 4. So that in page 3 (where the language selection is longer there) a text appears depending on the language selected in page 1.

The language selection in page 1 is:

```
<select id="languages" onchange="submit();">
<option value="en" >English</option>
<option value="es" selected>Spanish</option>
<option value="fr">French</option>
</select>
```

The cookie should be set immediately as soon as the page opens the first time and the value should get updated if the user changes the language in the drop-down menu from page 1. The cookie should be kept until page 4.

Any ideas how to set the cookie and then read it so the text in page page 3 appears in the language chosen in page 1?

The text that needs to appear in the selected language is not part of the HTML and it's being inserted via Javascript as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if ($('page_3').length) {
$('#my_element').after('<div id="greet"></div>XXXXXX</div>');
}
});
```

The code should first check the language value from the cookie and replace the 'XXXXXX' with the respective text depending on the language cookie value:

```
var welcome = {
en:"English",
es:"Espanol",
fr:"Francais"
}
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#greet').html(welcome[$('#languages').val()]);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: did you try looking here allready? http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Are you only using the cookie value client-side?

Comment: I would need only the cookie value "en" or "es" or "fr"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, I would recommend taking a look at a wonderful cookie plugin: [**jQuery Cookie Plugin**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie):

To set a cookie you would use:

```
$.cookie('name', 'value');
```

And to read, even easier:

```
$.cookie('name');
```

In you case, you would have to leverage, the select's change event to change the cookie, and page load to read the cookie.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e7skfjqj/)

And your greeting would go something like:

```
var welcome = {
    en:"English",
    es:"Espanol",
    fr:"Francais"
},

//read previously set cookie value
language = $.cookie( 'language' );

$(document).ready(function () {

    //use value of cookie as key in welcome object to retrieve the language.
    $('#greet').html( welcome[language] );

});
```

Comment: how would I add the text for the element '#greet' depending on the cookie value? I wrote '#languages' but this was for the case of page 1. On page 3 the element '#languages' does not exist

Comment: @adrian.m123, if this answer was helpful, don't forget to accept it. Enjoy!